# Why setting object that is undergoing deallocation to weak property results in crash

Tags: objective-c, clang, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references, dealloc

In [Clang's Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#semantics) we see the following

> For __weak objects, the lvalue is updated to point to the new pointee, unless the new pointee is an object currently undergoing deallocation, in which case the lvalue is updated to a null pointer. This must execute atomically with respect to other assignments to the object, to reads from the object, and to the final release of the new pointee.

In [objc-weak.mm](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-680/runtime/objc-weak.mm) wee see the following chunk of code in `weak_register_no_lock()`:

```
    if (deallocating) {
    if (crashIfDeallocating) {
        _objc_fatal("Cannot form weak reference to instance (%p) of "
                    "class %s. It is possible that this object was "
                    "over-released, or is in the process of deallocation.",
                    (void*)referent, object_getClassName((id)referent));
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

I set a breakpoint in my UIViewController subclass `dealloc` method and tried invoking `[self allowsWeakReference]` in lldb which resulted in `NO` value.

If we try to set self to weak property of another object the app will crash in accordance with the objc-weak.mm code.

The question is – why does this happen? Is the clang's specification wrong? Is is this a bug in objc implementation?

---

Here is a simple piece of code that will reproduce the crash:

```
//cc -fmodules -fobjc-arc -g crash.m -o crash
@import Foundation;

@interface Foo : NSObject
@end

@implementation Foo
- (void)dealloc {
  Foo * __weak weakSelf = self; // crashes on this line
}
@end

int main() {
  (void)[[Foo alloc] init];
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what is it you want to know; why your app crashes or why setting a weak pointer to a deallocating object results in null?  Also why have you assumed the two things are related?

Comment: I slightly edited my question to use the latest objc-weak.mm source.

Comment: But you didn't answer my questions.

Comment: Sorry, I pressed enter to quickly.
I see two contradicting statements. The first one is that setting a weak pointer to a deallocating object should result in nil. But in the source code of objc-weak we see that it will result in crash instead. I was assuming that it is perfectly legal to store `self` to weak properties during the deallocation, but now I see that it isn't. Isn't it a bug?

Comment: And what sets `crashIfDeallocating`?

Comment: It is the argument in weak_register_no_lock function. Where it is coming from and on what it depends I don't know

Comment: Well that seems to be the key as to weather it performs as documented or crashes as you claim.  I would assume, therefore, that's passed as `false` most/all of the time.  You'd have to do further tracing in the source code to actually see what affects it.

Comment: I'm sure that it crashes because I reproduced it. I didn't find anything that suggests that crash is the expected behaviour.

Comment: It doesn't sound like what you're testing is a scenario described by the first quote.  You are setting a pointer from within an object that is being dealloc'd, not setting a pointer **to** an object being dealloc'd.

Comment: Frankly, I didn't quite get what you're saying. If I write `someObject.delegate = self` in the `dealloc` method, then I'm setting a pointer **to** an object that is currently undergoing deallocation.

Comment: In `NSObject.mm`, you can see that `objc_initWeak` and `objc_storeWeak` pass crash = true, and there are also functions called `objc_initWeakOrNil` and `objc_storeWeakOrNil` that don't crash. I agree that this contradicts the ARC spec, where in the section for runtime functions at the end it explicitly says that `objc_initWeak` and `objc_storeWeak` are to store a null pointer if the pointee is undergoing deallocation.

Comment: Looking at the history of [obcj4 source](https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/), this behavior began in version 680 (corresponding to OS X 10.11 and iOS 9), and didn't exist in the previous version 647, where there was only one version of the functions `objc_initWeak` and `objc_storeWeak`, and they don't crash.

Comment: Likely needed for Swift …

Comment: A weak reference doesn't have ownership of the object. When the variable it was referencing it discarded, the weak reference disappears and is set to nil.

Comment: It seems I misspoke earlier about this beginning in version 680. In earlier versions, there was only one version, but it seems from looking at the source of `weak_register_no_lock` that it always crashes when deallocating.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug: it's obviously very intentional. It is a deviation from the spec, but it's an intentional one.

Based on the warning, it sounds like they wanted to make it easier to diagnose over-release scenarios, and catching objects that are being deallocated at the time might just be a side effect of that main goal.

They might also consider that, if you're trying to weakify `self` while being deallocated anyway, and you're not checking for a `nil` weakref (quite common - lots of block code repeatedly calls through a weakref that could go `nil` at any time!), you're setting yourself up for hard to debug bugs.

All that said, I'd love to see the notes behind that runtime change.